# Kubernetes deployment wipes out persistent volume

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to setup a containerised application with kubernetes and I am facing an issue. When I change the image of the app and redeploy the persistent volume seems to be wiped out - for example if I do a deployment with v1.0.0 and then a new deployment with v1.0.1 . I have tried setting up the app with Deployment and StatefuSet but result is the same, check the code below.

I am fairly new to Kubernetes and any help will be appreciated.

Option 1 (StatefulSet):

```yaml
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-admin-db-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: ''
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /var/lib/postgresql-test-admin-db/
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: admin-node
  labels:
    app: admin-node
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"backendConfig-test"}}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: admin-node
  ports:
    - name: test-web-port
      port: 80
      targetPort: 4000
      protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: admin-node
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: admin-node
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: admin-node
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: test-admin-db-claim
      spec:
        storageClassName: ''
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        volumeName: test-admin-db-pv
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: admin-node
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - image: 'postgres:10.4'
          name: admin-db
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: db
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: dbuser
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: dbpassword
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
              name: admin-db
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test-admin-db-claim
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql
        - image: 'eu.gcr.io/my-project/my-image:v1.0.0'
          name: admin-node
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4000
              name: admin-node
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /api/health
              port: 4000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 10
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /api/health
              port: 4000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 10
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: development
            - name: LOG_LEVEL
              value: info
            - name: NAMESPACE
              value: test
            - name: DB_DB
              value: db
            - name: DB_HOST
              value: 0.0.0.0
            - name: DB_PASS
              value: dbpassword
            - name: DB_USER
              value: dbuser
            - name: DB_PORT
              value: '5432'
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Option 2 (Deployment):

```yaml
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-admin-db-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: ''
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  claimRef:
    name: test-admin-db-claim
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /var/lib/postgresql-test-admin-db/
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: test-admin-db-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: ''
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeName: test-admin-db-pv
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: admin-node
  labels:
    app: admin-node
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"backendConfig-test"}}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: admin-node
  ports:
    - name: test-web-port
      port: 80
      targetPort: 4000
      protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: admin-node
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: admin-node
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: admin-node
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: 'postgres:10.4'
          name: admin-db
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: db
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: dbuser
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: dbpassword
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
              name: admin-db
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test-admin-db-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql
        - image: 'eu.gcr.io/my-project/my-image:v1.0.0'
          name: admin-node
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4000
              name: admin-node
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /api/v1/health
              port: 4000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 10
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /api/v1/health
              port: 4000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 10
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: development
            - name: LOG_LEVEL
              value: info
            - name: NAMESPACE
              value: test
            - name: DB_DB
              value: db
            - name: DB_HOST
              value: 0.0.0.0
            - name: DB_PASS
              value: dbpassword
            - name: DB_USER
              value: dbuser
            - name: DB_PORT
              value: '5432'
      volumes:
        - name: test-admin-db-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: test-admin-db-claim
      restartPolicy: Always
```

**Edit**
Since it was mentioned I am sharing the persistent volume info (the reclaim policy is already set to Retain)

```
Name:            test-admin-db-pv
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    
Status:          Bound
Claim:           wipetestdep/test-admin-db-claim-admin-node-0
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        10Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:         
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/lib/postgresql-wipetestdep-admin-db/
    HostPathType:  
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this? I am having the exact same issue. I also have my `reclaimPolicy` set to `Retain` already.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/#why-change-reclaim-policy-of-a-persistentvolume)

> PersistentVolumes can have various reclaim policies, including
> "Retain", "Recycle", and "Delete". For dynamically provisioned
> PersistentVolumes, the default reclaim policy is "Delete". This means
> that a dynamically provisioned volume is automatically deleted when a
> user deletes the corresponding PersistentVolumeClaim. This automatic
> behavior might be inappropriate if the volume contains precious data.
> In that case, it is more appropriate to use the "Retain" policy. With
> the "Retain" policy, if a user deletes a PersistentVolumeClaim, the
> corresponding PersistentVolume is not be deleted. Instead, it is moved
> to the Released phase, where all of its data can be manually
> recovered.

Change the reclaim policy to `Retain` using

```
kubectl patch pv <your-pv-name> -p '{"spec":{"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Retain"}}'
```

where `<your-pv-name>` is the name of your chosen `PersistentVolume`

Comment: The persistent volume is with Retain reclaim policy already

Name:            test-admin-db-pv
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    
Status:          Bound
Claim:           test/test-admin-db-claim-admin-node-0
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem